# Undefined BLAS functions even after including -lreflblas

Tags: function, header, fortran, lapack, blas

I am trying to compile a code which makes use of Lapack functions. I installed Lapack and BLAS following the main instructions of (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn81.pdf), I ran the tests and it sounds OK.

However, when I run :

```
gfortran -L/home/user/Desktop/LAPACK -I/home/user/Desktop/LAPACK/include -llapack -llapacke -lrefblas -O3 lorenz96v4.f90 -o l96_2.x -ffree-line-length-200
```

I obtain a pile of errors (see below). The libraries liblapak.a and librefblas.a are contained in /home/user/Desktop/LAPACK and all the header files are in the include folder therein.

Here are the error messages :

```
In function `testcorrelation_':
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x132d): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x171e): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x1787): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
/tmp/ccU96uz3.o: In function `qr_':
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x1da0): undefined reference to `dorm2r_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x1dcb): undefined reference to `dgeqrf_'
/tmp/ccU96uz3.o: In function `rungekutta4thtl_':
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x3653): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x36bf): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x3726): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x375a): undefined reference to `dlaset_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x3c88): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x3cf4): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x3d53): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x3d84): undefined reference to `dlaset_'
/tmp/ccU96uz3.o: In function `MAIN__':
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0x8cd6): undefined reference to `dgemm_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xa023): undefined reference to `dlaset_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xa195): undefined reference to `ilaenv_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xa276): undefined reference to `dgeqrf_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xb343): undefined reference to `dlaset_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xb4b5): undefined reference to `ilaenv_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xbfa2): undefined reference to `dgeqrf_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xc30d): undefined reference to `dtrtrs_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xc399): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
lorenz96v4.f90:(.text+0xceb5): undefined reference to `dorm2r_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks like the compiler did not recognize or find the headers... Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens if you do `gfortran -L/home/user/Desktop/LAPACK  -O3 lorenz96v4.f90 -o l96_2.x -ffree-line-length-200 -I/home/user/Desktop/LAPACK/include -llapack -llapacke -lrefblas` i.e., put the libraries at the end? What if you do `gfortran lorenz96v4.f90 /home/user/Desktop/LAPACK/librefblas.a ....`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ln -s /home/user/Desktop/LAPACK/librefblas.a /home/user/Desktop/LAPACK/libblas.a
```

Also use -lblas and change linking order:

```
-llapacke -llapack -lblas
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work... I still get the same errors.